# How to render specific FBO Texture attachment (assume attachment1) with 2 attached

Tags: textures, rendering, fbo

1. Create FBO & its textures like normal.

   ```
   // FBO & Texture
   glGenFramebuffers(1, &mFbo);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFbo);
   glGenTextures(2, mTexture);

   for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
       // Init texture
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[i]);
       glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, \
           0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
       glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
       glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
       glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
       glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
       glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

       // attach to FBO
       glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, \
           mTexture[i], 0);
   }
   glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
   glUseProgram(0);
   ```
2. Bind FBO and render it inside draw loop.

   ```
   // Preparing FBO texture.
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFbo);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   GLuint at0[1] =  {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
   GLuint at1[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+1};

   glDrawBuffers(1, at0);
   // Filled texture attachment0 less white (transparency = 0.5f)
   GUtils::VideoDriver::GetInstance()->DrawFillRect(glm::vec2(0,0), \
           SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, glm::vec4(glm::vec3(1.0f/(1)), 0.5f));

   glDrawBuffers(1, at1);
   // Filled texture attachment0+1 white.
   GUtils::VideoDriver::GetInstance()->DrawFillRect(glm::vec2(0,0), \
           SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, glm::vec4(glm::vec3(1.0f/(1)), 1.0f));

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   ```

After all things I did above:

- texture attachment0 (mTexture[0]) will be filled in less white.
- texture attachment1 (mTexture[1]) will be filled in white.

**Right?**

I cannot understand when render FBO texture:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[index]);
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

1. mTexture[0] , screen = **white**. (It must be **less White**)
2. mTexture[1] , screen = **black**. (It must be **White**)

Firstly, Did i do a right way to render attached FBO texture or am I misunderstood fbo attachment?

Lastly, How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your fragment shader write to `gl_FragColor`? I suspect that when you try to write your second texture you are actually overwriting your first one. `glDrawBuffers` only defines where writes to user defined outputs (i.e. those using `layout(location = 0) out` ...) go, so all of your fragment writes are going to the texture attached to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`

Comment: ah ha, I think I got a bit of understanding :) need more time to investigate. But thank all of you, guys. You are my angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use **Multiple Render Targets** you need to use pixel shaders to tell the GPU where to send each color values.

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 my_first_FBO_color_buffer;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 my_second_FBO_color_buffer;

void main() {
   my_first_FBO_color_buffer = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
   my_second_FBO_color_buffer = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

See [What is the recommended way to output values to FBO targets? (OpenGL 3.3 + GLSL 330)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49667/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-output-values-to-fbo-targets-opengl-3-3-glsl)

Comment: Sorry that I do not really understood. Because I think each texture has its paticular data. Can I render each texture in sequence? I mean the first will be rendered at position 0,0. The second will be rendered at 100, 100 (assume that) or just render the only one like my dummy code above. attach 2, but render only second... Can I do that?

Comment: Thank you, Stephane. Now i know what I have to do. Thank you very much